# How to check if a float is lesser than 0 in QWEB report

Tags: odoo, qweb

I want to know if there is a special keyword as alternative to `>` in QWEB report.
I found `gt (maps to >)` but it shows the following error message:

```
QWebException: invalid syntax (, line 1)
```

*Code*:

```
<t t-if="total gt 0">
    <t t-esc="total"/>
</t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use html codes or in this situation you can use the named codes, too.

```
> = &gt; = &#62;
< = &lt; = &#60;
```

Comment: I was hoping a solution without html coding.

Comment: what's the problem with this solution? QWeb is a templating engine, mostly used to generate html. You have to use xml with it, and < and > are key syntax markers, so you can't use them here :-/